# GPU Caches and Atomics OpenCL

Tags: c++, caching, opencl, gpu, nvidia

I would like to know how GPU caches work exactly, and how atomic operations work on global data (say for example on the new Nvidia Maxwell architecture).
Say I have the following code snippet (assuming multiple threads are reading and writing to cache lines containing D[u] and D[v]):

```
__global float* D

(*(float*)a = D[u];
(*(float*)b = D[v] + c;         //where c is some arbitrary value

while ((readback = atomic_cmpxchg((__global uint*)D[u], a, b)) != a)
{
  a = readback;                 //read both again on a failue
  (*(float*)b = D[v] + c;
}
```

Now if some other thread writes to D[u] then the compare and swap will fail and we have to retry by reading the updated value of D[u]. However, in conventional CPU multicores, we know that the underlying cache coherence will bring the new value of D[v] to this thread if some other threads write to D[v].

However GPUs don't follow this type of coherence for writes that must be visible to all threads if they want to read. Any ideas on how this works out in GPUs (if other threads are writing to D[v] and we are not failing on it in the atomic_cmpxchg)?

Thanks

Comment: != is computed first, then result assigned to readback as true/false (probably 1/0). Did you mean assignment first and then comparison?

Comment: no. so you read D[u] and D[v] before you do the atomic. The atomic then fails if the value of D[u] changed in between the read and the atomic. 
However this is not done in the case of D[v], which could also change.

In multicores the cache coherence protocol brings you the latest value of D[v] if it was changed by a thread. However this is not in the case of GPUs. So I wanted to ask would GPUs read stale value of D[v] in this case?